# Метод простых итераций C++

Tags: c++, математика

Требуется написать функцию поиска корня уравнения на интервале методом простых итераций с заданной точностью. Уравнение [image]. Интервал я нашел, `[1; 2]`. Проблема в моем непонимании сути самого метода. Необходимо функцию выразить как `x = fi(x)` - как это вообще сделать? Ну и интересует реализация этого алгоритма на C++, хотя бы похожий пример.

Comment: Формулы хорошо смотрятся, когда оформлены как код. Ctrl+K или вручную backtick (`) с обоих сторон.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Долго рассказывать теорию, ее почитайте сами. В общем, если есть уравнение `x = f(x)`, да при этом около корня (вернее, там, где работать будем) производная `f(x)` по модулю была меньше единицы, то просто очередное приближение получается как значение функции от предыдущего.

В вашем варианте можно привести к виду

```
x = (1/(4*ln(x))-1)^2
```

или

```
x = e^(1/(4(1+sqrt(x))))
```

Проверьте сами, что условие выполняется во втором случае. 
Вскользь замечу, что бывают вариант, когда просто так условие сходимости не выполняется и приходится маяться, хитро модифицируя функции, но это совсем за рамками ответа.

А дальше все просто, как табурет:

```
using namespace std;

inline double sq(double x) { return x*x; }

const double eps = 0.00000001;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    double x0 = 1.5,  // Начальное приближение
           x1 = 2;
    for(;;)
    {
        x1 = exp(1.0/(4.0*(1+sqrt(x0))));
        if (fabs(x1 - x0) < eps) break;
        x0 = x1;
    }
    cout << x1 << endl;
}
```

Comment: А существует ли необходимость находить производную заданной функции чтобы проверить, что отображение является сжимающим?

Comment: Я бы сказал так - если сходимость имеет место, то можно и не дергаться...